# Mysql join order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as follows:

Table user_prefs:

```
user_prefs_id    int(11) PK
user_id          int(11)
item             varchar(128) PK
category_id      smallint(6)
parent           smallint(6)
rank             tinyint(4)
dateadded        datetime
```

Table categories:

```
category_id      int(11) PK
name             varchar(255)
main_category    varchar(64)
parent           int(6)
isparent         enum('No','Yes')
display_rank     int(9)
active           enum('Yes','No')
```

I am doing a select from `user_prefs` based on `user_id`, but I want to sort by category name which is in the categories table - `category_id` is matched between the two tables

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user_prefs u
   JOIN categories cat ON u.category_id = cat.category_id
WHERE p.user_id = 10 /* Put user id here*/
ORDER BY cat.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.*, c.category
from user_prefs u
INNER JOIN categories c ON u.category_id = c.category_id
order by c.name
```

Comment: you forgot to alias your tables

Answer (score 0):

Sure...

```
SELECT p.*
FROM user_prefs p
JOIN categories c ON (p.cateogory_id = c.category_id)
WHERE p.user_id = ?
ORDER BY c.name;
```

Comment: He doesn't explicitly say, but this query forgets to so select the category name.  Kinda seems like it would be appropriate here.

Comment: I figured if he wanted that, he would have already been doing a join, and there would have been no reason to ask the question. :) (Or it would have been an entirely different question--`How do I join two tables?`)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
SELECT up.*, c.name
FROM user_prefs up
JOIN categories c ON c.category_id = up.category_id
WHERE up.user_id = ?
ORDER BY c.name;
```